# Which is correct Challenges exist or challenges exists

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I need to submit a memo with the statement challenges exist. Which is correct Challenges exist or challenges exists

Comment: Is your confusion about whether or not "challenges" is plural? Why would you think it isn't? Third-person plural and regular English verb conjugation.

Answer (score 1):

If the verb "**to exist**" refers to "**challenges**" in your context then it will always be "**exist**" since "**challenges**" is a plural word. However, if the verb refers to something other than "**challenges**" then it may be either singular or plural depending on the word the verb refers to. Here are a few silly examples from me *(just to go with the explanation)*:

- Such **challenges** **exist** only in adult life.
- The **spirit** of competing in challenges **exists** in my life.
- Many different **ways** to win in challenges **exist** in nature.